# In Matlab when issuing a custom warning, the message-id is not being recognized. How do I correct this?

Tags: matlab, compiler-warnings

I am issuing a warning in my code like -

```
warning('Custom:data-missing','Can''t access Customer Terms for data point #%d.',i)
```

When this is triggered on the command window I see

```
Warning: Custom:data-missing 
> In asr_stfr_terms at 97
```

Why is this happening? Instead of the warning message, why is Matlab printing the message_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '-' is not allowed.

```
warning('Custom:dataMissing','Can''t access Customer Terms for data point #%d.',i)
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Seems I did something silly in the end. Do you know  if this is mentioned in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: @UditG: Did not find anything, otherwise I would have mentioned the allowed characters.

Comment: If you type `help warning` you'll see that it does say there that the message ID has to be constructed from components that are alphanumeric strings (i.e. just letters and numbers, no punctuation other than the colon to separate components of the message). For some reason this information isn't revealed by `doc warning`, though. Either way, it's a pretty annoying restriction that I can't see the need for.

Comment: Thanks Daniel & Sam.
@SamRoberts Thanks for that explanation mate.